# Custom attribute not getting called without Filterattribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know attributes don't do anything by themselves. Is there any way to call them? Please give me some suggestion with an example?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All| AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class LoggerAttribute: Attribute {

    public LoggerAttribute()
    {
        //something 
    }

}

[Logger]
public  List<string> MyMethod(...) { ... }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you expect as result of " Is there any way to call them"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually, I want to create a log for each method so, I have created **LoggerAttribute** for it, but when **MyMethod** is called **LoggerAttribute** not being hit

Comment: You need something that will intercept calls to `MyMethod` and check its attributes... This is way too broad for a question, but https://www.bing.com/search?q=unity+logging+interception+C%23 should give you some ideas (that search is for Unity container, other containers will have similar functionality... you may also get just interception/proxying part separately from DI part of such libraries sometime)